# How to return an array in JNI?

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I have a native function I am accessing via JNI that needs to return the contents of an array to java. My function prototype is as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT jcharArray JNICALL Java_jniusb_Main_receiveData
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jchar);
```

which was generated with javah.exe.

So in the function's code I have an array 'unsigned char InputPacketBuffer[65]' which i want to return to java.  However, I am having problems mapping this to my return type 'jcharArray'.

In another function I used the 'GetCharArrayRegion' method provided by JNI to convert an input parameter of type 'jcharArray' to a 'jchar' array which i could then typecast to an 'unsigned char' array.  Basically, I need to do the opposite of this to convert in the other direction, but I haven't been able to find an appropriate JNI method in the JNI specification pdf.  Anyone know how to do this?

UPDATE:

I found the correct JNI function on andy's link - SetCharArrayRegion().

fyi - the "The Java Native Interface - programmer's guide and specification" gives incorrect examples for using their functions.

i.e.

```
(*env)->SetCharArrayRegion(env, elemArr, 0, len, chars);
```

doesn't compile.  Instead, the proper syntax is:

```
(*env).SetCharArrayRegion(elemArr, 0, len, chars);
```

Comment: The examples are correct for C code, in which the typedef for JNIEnv is a structure of JNI function pointers. For a C++ method call, just omit the first argument of the documented JNI function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [JNI documentation on array operations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#array_operations). The counterpart to `GetCharArrayRegion` is `SetCharArrayRegion`.

A jchar is a short, not a char. Java supports Unicode characters. If you want an array of bytes, you can use jbytearray.

An alternative is to use [JNI string operations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations).

Comment: all of these arrays are 64-bytes (unsigned 8-bits) so they need to be 'unsigned char' in vc++.  jchar was the closest thing i could find to map to in JNI - even though it is unsigned 16-bit, i can successfully typecast it to an 'unsigned char' since i make sure that the java side never exceeds the bounds.  I can't use the jbyte type because it is signed 8-bits and doesn't have the range i need.

Comment: You mentioned casting the array - that wouldn't work. Casting individual characters would work; you could also use bytes and convert on the Java side. [Edited answer with the counterpart to the specific method you mentioned in the last paragraph.]

Comment: yeah i know, by that i meant running a 'for' loop with each element typecasted appropriately.  anyways, do you have to call the 'release array' function when using 'getarrayregion' - or is it only for 'getarrayelements'?

Comment: No, the release methods are for the similarly named get methods that might return a direct pointer to the array. Sorry for the initial misdirection; on the first read I missed the specific method you were already using.